# Java File Parsing based on Position

Tags: java, parsing

Actually I am trying to parse a txt file using Java(`StringTokenizer`).
I am taking each record as a string and parsing it as there are no delimiter.
FirstRow is the overall Header.
Second record headerRecord record followed by its Details record.
Last record is the trailer record.

QUESTION:How will I validate/parse that for each header record there are one or more detail record.if not throw an error.

```
HEADER                  0010120140602090500000000
HEDREC1000000001       yyy 0327201404262014Z3USD    eTCINTERFACE
DETREC2000000001       yyy           22222 bbbbb 44           0001140000.00C 
DETREC2000000001       yyy           22222 aaaaa 44           0001140000.00D  
HEDREC1000000002       yyy 0327201404262014Z3USD    eTCINTERFACE
DETREC2000000002       yyy           22222 bbbbb 44           0001140000.00C 
TRAILER                  001012014060209050000000003
```

thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: What did you try already to parse that thing? How would you associate a detail record with a header in your code?

Comment: Please show the effort you have made so far.

Comment: And please show an invalid example.

Comment: My suggestion is that you use a library for this instead. A lot of alternatives are listed here: http://jsapar.blogspot.com/p/links.html and https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar is one suggestion but there are a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use StringTokenizer for fixed records.

There are two cases:

- fixed record size
- record terminator

With a record terminator, like a regular newline, it is simplest:

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {
    for (;;) {
        String record = in.readLine();
        if (record == null) {
            break;
        }
        String field1 = record.substring(0, 16).trim();
        String field2 = record.substring(16, 20);
        ...
   }
}
```

(trim removing spaces at both sides.)

For a fixed length record use `byte[RECORD_LENGTH]` and read using a

```
byte[] record = new byte[120];
try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream))) {
    for (;;) {
        int nread = in.read(record);
        if (nread < record.length) {
            break;
        }
        String recordS = new String(record, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        ...
```

For efficiency sake, you might look into memory mapped I/O, `ByteBuffer`.